# Basic HTML format

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I need to know the basic structure of HTML as I started coding today and Have no reference.

I just know my friend told me to start your programming journey from stackoverflow.

I have only studied html in 6th class for once and now i don't remember it.

Comment: You should start googling an HTML tutorial instead of asking these questions here. That should get you up and running quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your friend gave you incorrect information. This site is for *specific* programming-related questions, it is not a resource for learning. Take a look at some online guides and tutorials, and if you have a *specific* question, search the site for an answer (99% of newbie questions have already been asked!) and if you still can't find an answer, see [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting here :)

Comment: https://html5boilerplate.com/ might be a good reference to begin with if it's a boilerplate structure you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic HTML format and You can check the reference from the below link

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        tittle
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    body
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp

Comment: can i learn full html from w3school website ?

Comment: Yes. W3Schools is the best Website for the beginners. 
You can learn almost every thing that you want to know about any language from W3School. 

So, I would prefer going to w3schools and than any other source. 
Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just went through w3schools. I dont have any support right now. So thanks for your support. I will let you know if I am stuck with anything.